# Missing many UI elements

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

In an attempt to clear device from tons of ads randomly opening and covering whole screen, I have uninstalled majority of preinstalled software (like TurboCleaner and MegaShop or something like that). After doing it there are no more ads covering whole screen, but also system UI is broken - there is no status bar (the top bar with notifications), software buttons are not present (device doesn't have hardware buttons), after installing app for software buttons I also discovered that showing all running apps (the square button) is not working (I think it was broken even before a restart, when status bar was still present). Tried installing Nova launcher in hope that it could fix the missing status bar, but even after toggling the option in settings it did nothing.

Any ideas? I would prefer not to do a factory reset - I think it will only bring back those full-screen ads displaying every few minutes, in lock screen and so on.

Device: Prestigio MultiPad Wize 3131 3G
OS: Android 6.0
The tablet is not rooted or modified in any similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these bloat-wares are included into the ROM itself and removing these can cause system issues, you are facing the same problem here.

I would suggest you to -

- reinstall all the preloaded apps and check the result.

For preventing unwanted ads you could disable those apps or, use some sort of ad-blocker/ network firewall app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am confused with the answer, can you pls tell the answer.

Comment: Try to reinstall all apps you have uninstalled, it should work.